# How to use or not use a native library in different flavor?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

我有个安卓项目，在配制项目变体时，某些Flavor需要原生库，某些不需要。
我知道如何为不同的Flavor配置不同的原生库，但不知道如何让某些flavor使用原生库而另一些不使用原生库。
请问我该怎么配置？
I have an Android project. When configuring project variants, some flavors require a native library, some are not. 
I know how to configure different native libraries for different flavors, but I don't know how to make some flavors use native libraries, others do not use native libraries. 
How can I configure it?

在build.gradle中，我是如下配置的：
In build.gradle, I configured it as follows:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "lhl.wenshi"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        ndk {
            // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
            // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions 'hardware'
    productFlavors {
        no_hardware {
            dimension = 'hardware'
            applicationIdSuffix = '.nohw'
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    targets // How to not use the native library?
                }
            }
        }
        hardware {
            dimension = 'hardware'
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    targets "nalib"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

我是用cmake编译的原生代码，库的名字叫做nalib，我不想在no_hardware这个flavor中使用原生库，请问我该怎么做？谷歌官方给出的示例让不同的flavor使用不同的原生库，但如何让某些flavor不使用原生库呢？
I use cmake to compile native code. The name of the library is called nalib. I don't want to use the native library in the no_hardware flavor. What should I do? The example given by Google officially allows different flavors to use different native libraries, but how to make certain flavors not use native libraries?